# DynamoDB hierarchical one-to-many update-friendly pattern

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, hierarchical-data, dynamodb-queries

I have heirarchical data that need to support CRUD operations on all levels. I have seen patterns like composite key with hash bangs mentioned in https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-one-to-many/#composite-sort-keys-with-hierarchical-data , this is very smart for retrieving things but it doesn't seem efficient enough for updating things.

For example if I have to update a `country` name which has 50 `states` and those 50 `states` have 50 `cities`, the I need to update a whooping 2500 records just to update the country name. Same goes with updating a state name which needs 50 records to be updated.

A reasonable alternative to this seems to be maintaining Global Secondary indices for `states` and `cities` apart from a primary partition key on `country`. Is that the best way or am I missing a better approach?

Bonus: I need the best update-friendly approach for not just a 3 level heirarchy but a 4 or 5 or potentially a n level hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

It's worse than you think...

DDB doesn't allow you to update the key of an existing record.  You'd have to delete those 2500 records and re-add them.

Luckily, countries don't change their names that often..

Without knowing more about your actual data, I can't offer any suggestions other than you may want to consider Aurora instead of DDB.

Comment: I just gave the countries example because the linked blog post has them but you can imagine a similarly modeled data with country_id, state_id and city_id as keys and names as just regular fields that can be updated, I understand its hard to answer without actual data instead of this contrived example but I can't disclose that! Im already looking at alternative databases, thanks!